# jquery ajax post request fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

trying to send an ajax post request

```
function ajaxCall(request_data) {
alert(request_data['table'] + request_data['name'] + request_data['description']);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "../src/api.php/InsertTo",
    data: request_data,
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json',
    success: function() {
        alert('good');
        /* $('form').hide();
         $('h3').append("Object Successfully Inserted!");*/
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown + textStatus);
    }
});
```

it throws error every time, 'request_data' is an object and url return just a simple string for now, please find the problem

Comment: have you used `JSON.stringify(request_data)` before sending  the JSON request?Also can you share the format of `request_data` in the question which you are sending to the api

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: `code`            var request_data = {
                'table': 'students',
                'name': name,
                'email': email,
                'phone': phone
            } this is the variable , i check every parameter and it got its value

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `JSON.stringify()` method.

```
data: JSON.stringify(request_data)
```

Also, `contentType` is the type of data you're sending, so application/json; The default is application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8.

If you use `application/json`, you have to use `JSON.stringify()` in order to send **JSON** object.

`JSON.stringify()` turns a javascript object to **json** text and stores it in a string.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with the below code after using `JSON.stringify` on the request_data. As per the docs

"The JSON.stringify() method converts a JavaScript value to a JSON string, optionally replacing values if a replacer function is specified, or optionally including only the specified properties if a replacer array is specified."

As you are using `dataType: "json"` and `contentType: 'application/json;'` you should convert the javascript value to a proper JSON string.

Please find more in the below link

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```js
function ajaxCall(request_data) {
alert(request_data['table'] + request_data['name'] + request_data['description']);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    cache: false,
    url: "../src/api.php/InsertTo",
    data: JSON.stringify(request_data),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function(data) {
        alert('good');
        console.log(data); // print the returned object
        /* $('form').hide();
         $('h3').append("Object Successfully Inserted!");*/
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown + textStatus);
    }
});
```